# boundary of word-hyperbolic group

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, group-actions

Let $G$ be a word-hyperbolic group and let $\partial G$ be its (Gromov) boundary.
Do there exist criteria that imply that all non-trivial finite order elements of $G$ act fixed-point freely on $\partial G$?

Comment: Surely not, because the boundary is a tree and so every finite order element fixes a point? (I believe it forms a tree as this is where JSJ-decompositions come from, if I have interpreted Bowditch's paper on cut points and canonical splitting's correctly).

Comment: The boundary is certainly not always a tree. If the group acts properly and cocompactly on $\mathbb{H}^{n}$, the boundary is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Hmm. Can what you say happen in the one-ended case?

Comment: If $\partial G$ is connected, then $G$ has one end.

Comment: Oh yeah, Bowditch mentions that!

Comment: Note: cross-posted as http://mathoverflow.net/q/139025

Comment: With respect to my first comment - it is a "pre-tree", not a tree, and this induces an action on a tree.